# Visual Studio 2015 crashing onstart up, then restarting and crashing again in a continuous loop

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Visual Studio 2015 worked fine on windows 8.1 but I upgraded to windows 10. Visual studio crashes on start up and repeats this cycle. I was able to find out what was causing this using 2013 debugger -> "System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

I've tried to uninstall and reinstall it but the problem continues. Also I've tried to repair it in the control panel.

Comment: Makes me think of one tech guy from Microsoft who punned me yesterday, "We decided to reboot Azure because at Microsoft, we just love rebooting"

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where my Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 used to crash frequently, and installing this Microsoft Update helped me to stabilize it --

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/01/26/servicing-update-available-for-visual-studio-update-1/

I would suggest you to download this update and try.